# Force Browser and Document Mode in ASP.Net Application

Tags: asp.net, internet-explorer

IE9+ sometimes have Browser Mode/Document Mode set to earlier versions or set to compatibility mode.  This causes issues in my application whereby javascript doesn't run.

Is there a way to force these to be the latest standards or to a particular standard, or is there something in my document in the type or head that can define this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, totally possible. Just make sure you use the `content="IE-Edge"` in your Master/layout page. this ensures IE is running on its standard mode. If you want a specific mode, replace it with `content="IE9"` or `content="IE8"`

```
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=Edge">
```